# Audio element not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am currently working on a SharePoint page and trying to put an audio file on my page but it doesn't even display in IE8. It worked fine at the beginning but it is not even displaying now. Just to clarify it works perfectly in Chrome. Do you guys know any alternative that works?

```js
var audio = document.getElementById('mytrack');
setTimeout(function() {
  audio.play();
}, 4000);
```

```css
audio#mytrack {
 width:330px;
 height:40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <audio id="mytrack" controls>
  <source src="../downloads/wpw.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  <source src="../downloads/wpw.ogg" type="audio/ogg">  
  <source src="../downloads/wpwv.wav" type="audio/wav">
 </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: IE8 doesn't support the audio element (http://caniuse.com/#search=audio). You will need to supply an alternate method of playing the audio (https://html5tutorial.info/html5-audio.php)

Comment: Yes <audio> it isn't supported by IE8. I tried <object> too but it doesn't work either. Thanks for your suggestion Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use audio.js to solve this problem. Not sure if you wanted to use a plugin or not but this does work with IE8. I hope this helps!